# Сравнение содержимого на основе его типа

Tags: sql, postgresql, типы-данных

Есть функция, в которой сравнивается значение одной ячейки (in_value) со значением другой ячейки (value). Обе ячейки в таблице имеют одинаковый тип text, соответственно, сравнение происходит лексикографически. Реальное содержимое может быть не только текстом, но и числами. Как поправить условие, чтоб корректно сравнивать и их? Возможно создать приведение типов на основе содержимого?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION base.func(id INT, in_value TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF base.table AS $BODY$ DECLARE
    arg_1 base.table%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR arg_1 IN 
        SELECT *FROM base.table WHERE base.table.cell = id
    LOOP
        CASE arg_1.condition
            WHEN 0 THEN
                IF in_value = arg_1.value
                THEN RETURN NEXT arg_1;
                END IF;
            WHEN 1 THEN
                IF in_value > arg_1.value
                THEN RETURN NEXT arg_1;
                END IF;
            WHEN 2 THEN
                IF in_value < arg_1.value
                THEN RETURN NEXT arg_1;
                END IF;
        END CASE;
    END LOOP;
END$BODY$
```

Comment: Покажите полный текст функции. Создайте fiddle с тестовыми данными и покажите требуемый ответ на этих данных.

Comment: Дополнил код. Есть предположение, что можно через регулярку записать дополнительное ветвление и делать соответствующий каст если в ячейке одни числа.

Comment: *Реальное содержимое может быть не только текстом, но и числами. Как поправить условие, чтоб корректно сравнивать и их?* Я верно понимаю, что Вы хотите определять, может ли значение интерпретироваться как число, и если да, то конвертировать его в число перед сравнением, иначе не делать этого и сравнивать как текст? и при этом признака, число или текст в поле записи, структурой таблицы не предусмотрено? Потому как у меня не соотносится текст вопроса и то, что выполняется при ветвлении по `arg_1.condition` - там просто разные сравнения, и ничего связанного с типом данных.

Comment: Да, Вы правильно меня поняли. Сейчас все значения аргументов интерпретируются текстом, если прилетят числа, то получится что-то вроде 15 > 100 = true. В этом вся проблема. Дополнительных признаков для типа не предусмотрено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.е. нужно нечто типа

```sql
CASE WHEN     TRIM(in_value) SIMILAR TO '[+-]?(([0-9]+.?[0-9]*)|([0-9]*.?[0-9]+))'
          AND TRIM(value)    SIMILAR TO '[+-]?(([0-9]+.?[0-9]*)|([0-9]*.?[0-9]+))'
     THEN in_value::NUMERIC = value::NUMERIC
     ELSE in_value = value /* или больше-меньше */
END
```

?

Comment: Да, то что нужно. Благодарю.